# Sencha Touch: How to use Direct Proxy for Asynchronous API

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I have store which use direct proxy to get data from api, but how i can make it work for asynchronous apis? How I can implement callback function using direct function? ?

Store:

```
Ext.define('Audit.store.TaskList', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'Audit.model.Task',
    'Audit.api.TaskAPI'
],

config: {
    model: 'Audit.model.Task'
},


proxy: {
    type: 'direct',
    directFn: Audit.api.TaskAPI.getTasks
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setup correctly (assuming your `directFn` is valid).  The way to load this store with a callback function is to just call `store.load({ callback: myCallbackFn })`.  Look at the docs for more info:  http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load